# Unable to capture class with Brackets

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using the following code in Python to capture certain text values from a webpage.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url="https://example.com/page1.html"
response=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html5lib')
spans=soup.find_all('a',"menu-tags")
for span in spans:
  print(span.text)
```

It works perfectly when the input HTML page is having the following:

```
  <li class="foodie">
    <a href="../../-/british/" class="menu-tags" data-clickstream-city-cuisine-module>British</a>
    <span>,&nbsp</span>
    <a href="../../-/indian/" class="menu-tags" data-clickstream-city-cuisine-module>Indian</a>
    <span>,&nbsp</span>
    <a href="../../-/french/" class="menu-tags" data-clickstream-city-cuisine-module>French</a>
```

and correctly produces the following output:

```
British
Indian
French
```

However, when I use the following modified code on the following input HTML page containing the class which have brackets (), the output is NOT generated.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
import requests
url="https://example.com/page1.html"
response=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html5lib')
spans=soup.find_all('span',"Fw(600)")
for span in spans:
  print(span.text)
```

HTML code input:

```
<span class="Fw(600)">Pineapple</span><br/><span>Animal</span>: <span class="Fw(600)">Monkey</span><br/><span>
```

Expected output is

```
Pineapple
Monkey
```

But nothing is being generated.
Is it because of brackets in the class, and if so how to capture it?

Using single or double backslash(es) before brackets doesn't help either:

```
spans=soup.find_all('span',"Fw\(600\)")
spans=soup.find_all('span',"Fw\\(600\\)")
```

Comment: If you do a find on just "span", and then print the attrs of the items, what does it print as the class for these spans?

Comment: You need to specify the class to search for as a keyword argument with the keyword `class_`.   `spans = soup.find_all('span', class_="Fw(600)")`

Comment: @nigh_anxiety - Thanks. I modified the code as `spans = soup.find_all('span', class_="Fw(600)")`, but it isnt generating any output. Something seems to be missing.

Comment: It works based on your provided example - Are you sure the element is available in your `soup`? Just print it and search for your value. If it is not in an url would help to get a closer look to the issue.

Comment: @HedgeHog - You are right. It works as long as HTML is available in a local variable. Running in to scrap data from the site is not working because the site is somehow blocking the request. Printing the soup indicates this error - "<first few lines of HTML code from the page then the following error>  Will be right back...    Thank you for your patience." Is there anyway to grab the HTML without the site blocking it?

Comment: To keep question and context clean - This would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus and providing a url to reproduce the issue, maybe it needs additional parameter or the use of `selenium`, ... Simply drop the link to new question here.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to comment of [@nigh_anxiety](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17030540/nigh-anxiety)

> You need to specify the class to search for as a keyword argument with the keyword [`class_`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class)

You could also use [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) with escaping:

```
soup.select('.Fw\(600\)')
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<span class="Fw(600)">Pineapple</span><br/><span>Animal</span>: <span class="Fw(600)">Monkey</span><br/><span>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.select('.Fw\(600\)')
```

##### Output

```
[<span class="Fw(600)">Pineapple</span>, <span class="Fw(600)">Monkey</span>]
```